# pandas get.dummies API usage

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in csv and was loading this data using errors = pd.read_csv("error_data.csv").
The data csv contains as below. Now I want to [image]
I tried the following code. But could not succeed.

```
errors = pd.read_csv("error_data.csv").
error_count = pd.get_dummies(errors)
print(error_count)
error_count.columns = ['datetime', 'machineID', 'error1', 'error2', 'error3', 'error4', 'error5']

error_count = error_count.groupby(['machineID', 'datetime']).sum().reset_index()
```

CSV Data:

```
"datetime","machineID","errorID"
2019-01-06 3:00,CuringPress1,"error3"
2019-02-03 6:00,CuringPress1,"error4"
2019-02-21 11:00,CuringPress1,"error1"
2019-02-21 16:00,CuringPress1,"error2"
2019-03-20 6:00,CuringPress1,"error1"
2019-04-04 6:00,CuringPress1,"error5"
2019-05-04 6:00,CuringPress1,"error4"
2019-05-19 6:00,CuringPress1,"error2"
2019-05-19 6:00,CuringPress1,"error3"
2019-06-03 6:00,CuringPress1,"error5"
2019-06-18 6:00,CuringPress1,"error2"
2019-06-18 6:00,CuringPress1,"error3"
2019-08-02 6:00,CuringPress1,"error4"
2019-08-02 6:00,CuringPress1,"error5"
2019-10-31 6:00,CuringPress1,"error5"
2019-11-15 6:00,CuringPress1,"error1"
2019-12-15 6:00,CuringPress1,"error5"
2019-01-31 6:00,CuringPress2,"error2"
2019-01-31 6:00,CuringPress2,"error3"
2019-04-01 6:00,CuringPress2,"error2"
2019-04-01 6:00,CuringPress2,"error3"
2019-04-16 6:00,CuringPress2,"error1"
2019-04-28 5:00,CuringPress2,"error4"
2019-05-26 15:00,CuringPress2,"error1"
2019-05-31 6:00,CuringPress2,"error2"
2019-05-31 6:00,CuringPress2,"error3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can do:

```
df[['machineID','datetime']].join(pd.get_dummies(df.errorID))
```

Output:

```
       machineID          datetime  error1  error2  error3  error4  error5
0   CuringPress1   2019-01-06 3:00       0       0       1       0       0
1   CuringPress1   2019-02-03 6:00       0       0       0       1       0
2   CuringPress1  2019-02-21 11:00       1       0       0       0       0
3   CuringPress1  2019-02-21 16:00       0       1       0       0       0
4   CuringPress1   2019-03-20 6:00       1       0       0       0       0
5   CuringPress1   2019-04-04 6:00       0       0       0       0       1
6   CuringPress1   2019-05-04 6:00       0       0       0       1       0
7   CuringPress1   2019-05-19 6:00       0       1       0       0       0
8   CuringPress1   2019-05-19 6:00       0       0       1       0       0
9   CuringPress1   2019-06-03 6:00       0       0       0       0       1
10  CuringPress1   2019-06-18 6:00       0       1       0       0       0
11  CuringPress1   2019-06-18 6:00       0       0       1       0       0
12  CuringPress1   2019-08-02 6:00       0       0       0       1       0
13  CuringPress1   2019-08-02 6:00       0       0       0       0       1
14  CuringPress1   2019-10-31 6:00       0       0       0       0       1
15  CuringPress1   2019-11-15 6:00       1       0       0       0       0
16  CuringPress1   2019-12-15 6:00       0       0       0       0       1
17  CuringPress2   2019-01-31 6:00       0       1       0       0       0
18  CuringPress2   2019-01-31 6:00       0       0       1       0       0
19  CuringPress2   2019-04-01 6:00       0       1       0       0       0
20  CuringPress2   2019-04-01 6:00       0       0       1       0       0
21  CuringPress2   2019-04-16 6:00       1       0       0       0       0
22  CuringPress2   2019-04-28 5:00       0       0       0       1       0
23  CuringPress2  2019-05-26 15:00       1       0       0       0       0
24  CuringPress2   2019-05-31 6:00       0       1       0       0       0
25  CuringPress2   2019-05-31 6:00       0       0       1       0       0
```